# Server Client Communcation between heroku apps

Tags: heroku, websocket, socket.io

I have a server application built on nodejs and socket.io and a client application built with typescript and socket.io.

The two apps are separate git repos.

Can I host them as separate apps on heroku and allow communication between them or do they need to share repo/heroku app?

Comment: Yes, they can both be hosted - your client is just connecting to an endpoint which could be anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As heroku allow to open single port per application. You have to use separate heroku apps for:

> 1. Nodejs backend which includes socket.io
> 2. Front client application which built on Typescript.

You can share share Repo if you're not connected Git with Heroku Repo.
But in case you connected Github repo with Heroku app you need a separate Repo for both.